# PostgreSQL Explain: why does child have larger cost than parent?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Why do some of the lower planning nodes have a cost higher than that of the the top most node? In [this article](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html), I found this example

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM tenk1 t1, onek t2
WHERE t1.unique1 < 100 AND t1.unique2 = t2.unique2;

                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=198.11..268.19 rows=10 width=488)
   Merge Cond: (t1.unique2 = t2.unique2)
   ->  Index Scan using tenk1_unique2 on tenk1 t1  (cost=0.29..656.28 rows=101 width=244)
         Filter: (unique1 < 100)
   ->  Sort  (cost=197.83..200.33 rows=1000 width=244)
         Sort Key: t2.unique2
         ->  Seq Scan on onek t2  (cost=0.00..148.00 rows=1000 width=244)
```

The child node index scan has a larger cost than the merge join node. In the article it also says "It's important to understand that the cost of an upper-level node includes the cost of all its child nodes".

So why is the child cost bigger than its parent?

Comment: Note that `explain` will only give you an _estimate_. If you run `explain (analyze, verbose)` then it will give you the _real_ costs and row numbers. You might want to compare those to the estimates.

Comment: Even though it's the estimate, how can the parent be estimated to have less cost than children? The algorithm for estimating does not automatically add onto children's costs?

Comment: It looks to me like either an error, or that the examples in the doc were tweaked for display purposes and this was not modified correctly. The only situation I can think of where the sum of the child costs can exceed the parent is where the operation is aborted part way through by a LIMIT clause, as the documentation states.

Answer (score 0):

As you see cost does indeed include all children costs :)
And rows of child index could be more then the result cos you join in query. So if tenk1_unique2 is a composit unique key on unique2 and some other value and is the cheapest index for this join, it can hold 101 rows with one unique2 value... This way you have 101 comparing against 1 and having 1 row in result...

**Update1**
Cost of parent is the sum of children costs. But rows number of a child in join is bigger. But if you join 1 against 101, you get 1 in result. so Parent can have 1 row, while child 100 rows...

**Update2** I suppose sentense

> the cost of an upper-level node includes the cost of all its child nodes

is valid only for

> Estimated start-up cost

**Update3**

And my colleague says that Estimated total cost (656.28) comes before applying Filter...

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I don't understand your answer, can you please rephrase a little bit?

Comment: @ethanjyx Child cost is not bigger. It is rows that bigger. This is the answer in short. all the rest is example of possible reason...